# ORA-01461 (with > 4k varchar2) error Only in merge statement. Insert or update works fine

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, merge, ora-01461

Here is my clue...
I'm on oracle 11g. Searched a lot, but nothing found.

I need to execute DML operations, which can contain data > 4k characters.

If i use a sql block, directly in oracle, like the next one, everything works fine

```
declare 
  txtV varchar2(32000);
BEGIN 
  txtV:= 'MORE THAN 4k CHARS, here only few for readability' ; 
  Update FD_FILTERDEF 
     set SQLFILTER = txtV 
   where id='blabla';  
END;
```

BUT!!!
if i use merge statement, it gives me error `ORA-01461`

```
declare 
  txtV varchar2(32000);
BEGIN 
  txtV:= '' ; 
  MERGE INTO FD_FILTERDEF A 
        USING ( select  txtV C0 
                  from dual) ST 
           ON (A.CODE = 'bla bla') 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    Update set A.SQLFILTER = st.C0  
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    insert (CODE  ,SQLFILTER ) 
      values ('bla bla'  , ST.C0  );  
END;
```

If have some hint would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please show your table definition

Comment: What is the type of `fd_filterdef.sqlfilter` ? A `clob` maybe ?

Comment: FD_FILTERDEF.SQLFILTER is a CLOB column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
create table fd_filterdef
( code varchar2(10) primary key
, sqlfilter clob );

declare
    txtv varchar2(32000);
begin
    txtv := rpad('select statement, really really long', 5000, ' etc');

    merge into fd_filterdef a
    using (select 'bla bla' as code from dual) st
    on (a.code = st.code)
    when matched then
        update set a.sqlfilter = txtv
    when not matched then
        insert (code, sqlfilter)
        values (st.code,txtv);
end;
/

select code, length(sqlfilter) from fd_filterdef;

CODE       LENGTH(SQLFILTER)
---------- -----------------
bla bla                 5000
```

Selecting your long variable from dual implicitly casts it to a SQL `varchar2` which prior to 12c only holds up to 4000 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

you can't select varchar2 more than 4k https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm

see your code

```
 select  txtV C0 from dual
```

but in oracle 12c you can
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020

Comment: This is not totally true... if i use

`variable='text of more than 4k chars';`

and then

`select variable from dual`

i have no issues, so selecting a variable of more than 4k is, obviously, permitted.

The problem is not in select statement, but in merge one.

Comment: @Sabbe, if I try to `select v1 into v2 from dual` where `v1` is > 4k, I get `ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested` (in 11g at least).

Comment: @William Robertson yes, of course because it varchar2, not clob or other

Comment: That's true - so one solution is to change `textv` to a `clob`. However we avoid a load of complication by not passing the value through an SQL query at all.

Answer (score 0):

@William great hint, this you posted works.

But i'm quite sure i have tested a syntax very similar, in which the only difference was in the select statement,
The one you provided works fine... the following one will raise the error:

```
declare 
  txtV varchar2(32000);
BEGIN 
  txtV:= '5000 chars ....';
  MERGE INTO FD_FILTERDEF A 
        USING ( select  'not used' Code from dual) ST 
           ON (A.CODE = 'TESTCODE') 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    Update set A.SQLFILTER = txtV   --<<<< LOOK HERE I USE DIRECTLY THE VARIABLE DELCARED, NOT THE ONE FROM SELECT STMT 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    insert (CODE  ,SQLFILTER ) 
      values (st.code  , txtV  );  
END;
```

Comment: What error do you get? I only get a PK violation because changing the join condition makes it try to add a new row with the same code.

Comment: PK Violation!? ... why? Merge should never give PK violation error (if real pk is used in "ON" condition. Anyway the error i get using my first (not working) version is `ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column`

Comment: The code example above gives a PK violation because `a.code` does not match the literal `TESTCODE`, so the `when not matched then insert` clause is used. Two executions will attempt to insert the same row, and in my example I defined a PK on `code`. I'm not sure what it's meant to demonstrate.

Comment: @William Yes, you are right. I thought, erroneously, that using a direct key value, without obtaining it from the inner "select ..." of the "using...." statement, would work the same way. :)

Anyway, thanks again for your hint that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

@William   ... ok, maybe i've made a bit of confusion in writing down the scripts. I was surprised about the "pk error" cause in my mind i have the script done as follows. I intended to no use at all the "select" statement, just passing the code inside insert and update (as follows), cause i build the query programmatically and replace values with placeholders....
In this way, there is no pk error at all. In you examples, of course, cause in insert was used the code from the query, but in update was used the value "TESTCODE" ... so it was searching (and updating) for a code, but inserting another :P
Sorry for my mistake :)

```
declare 
  txtV varchar2(32000);
BEGIN 
  txtV:= '5000 chars ....';
  MERGE INTO FD_FILTERDEF A 
        USING ( select  'not used' Code from dual) ST 
           ON (A.CODE = 'TESTCODE') 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    Update set A.SQLFILTER = txtV   --<<<< LOOK HERE I USE DIRECTLY THE VARIABLE DELCARED, NOT THE ONE FROM SELECT STMT 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    insert (CODE  ,SQLFILTER ) 
      values ('TESTCODE'  , txtV  );  
END;
```